# AnyLogic batch and unbatch seems to lose the agent's parameter?

Tags: anylogic

I have an AnyLogic model working, and it seems that batch and unbatch causes the agent to lose its parameters.

I've created a MWE:

I have an agent, called MyAgent, with a parameter called `timeNeeded`. On startup it runs this: `timeNeeded = uniform_discr(1,100);`.

I then set up a very simple model like this:

[image: Simple model]

Here the:

- Source makes a `MyAgent` every 55 seconds
- Delay has a delay time of `agent.timeNeeded`

This runs no problem. E.g. after about 3000 seconds (model time) we have this:
[image: Model running].

Next, I make a simple addition of a batch and unbatch:

[image: Simple model with batch and unbatch]

where the only change is the addition of a batch and an unbatch. Obviously, the batch is not permanent. It's the default setting of 10 agents begin batched. Here's the settings:

[image: Batch settings]

Now it runs until it has to delay and then errors as follows:

[image: Error for running model 2]

The error in the console says:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
Unresolved compilation problem: 
    timeNeeded cannot be resolved or is not a field

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    timeNeeded cannot be resolved or is not a field

    at mwe.Main._delay_delayTime_xjal(Main.java:382)
    at mwe.Main$2.delayTime(Main.java:246)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay.delayTime(Unknown Source)
```

If I change the delay time to 50 (instead of `agent.timeNeeded`), then it runs without issues.

[image: Model working]

It's strange because the context menu of that delay shows `agent.timeNeeded` as a valid entry:

[image: Context menu]

Am I missing something obvious? And, if not, what is the work around to save the parameters of the agents coming through a batch-unbatch step?

Comment: Actually, it seems this is quite simple. You just need the unbatch to have an element agent of MyAgent

Comment: True. Feel free to post this as a full answer, helps others in the future as well. You need to tell the Unbatch what it should unbatch into. Alternatively in your Delay block, you could type-cast using `((MyAgent)agent).timeNeeded` as well (but this is error-prone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future person coming across this simple thing (probably me!), you need to make sure that the unbatch outputs to an element agent of the same time that was originally batched. So in the MWE, the **element agent** needs to be MyAgent:

[image: MWE - unbatch settings]

It will then recover the original parameters. If that is the default `agent` type, that it can't have a parameter because the parameter is not defined for that agent type.